# How to persist angular 4 variable across events?

Tags: angular

I have used ng2-table to display my data. The data is getting loaded to the table. And also the variable _columns is filled with the columns information.

But the issue is when I click on any column header to sort that column, then _columns is becoming empty.

_columns is becoming empty in onChangeTable method of ng-table.component.ts file. I am not sure what is causing to make this value to be empty. I am  also not refeshing or reloading the page but just clicking on a column header to sort that column.

If you take any backend programming language like python, a variable value persists until that process is killed but in angular 4 when a process will start and when it will be killed?

I just want to understand that is it creating a new process when the page is loaded and and creating another process when clicked on column header? I am using ng2-table for my angular 4 project.